# Syntax error in query expression, SQL via PYODBC

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

The exact error message is:

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (comma) in query expression 'occupied = False, electric = False, family = False, disabled = False'. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")

I've looked everywhere I can see but don't understand what I'm doing wrong, the line in question is as follows:

```py
spacelist = cursor.execute("SELECT space, distance1, distance2, distance3, distance4, distance5 FROM spaces WHERE occupied = False, electric = True")
```

Comment: Try: `WHERE occupied = False AND electric = True`

Comment: The WHERE clause is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
spacelist = cursor.execute("SELECT space, distance1, distance2, distance3, 
distance4, distance5 FROM spaces WHERE occupied = False AND electric = True")
```